# ROR model associations problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have models User and Message. Every user can send messages to other users. In User there are no fields related to the Message. In Message there are the following: from_id, to_id, content.

I was trying to work it myself, but got confused after a few minutes.

What combination of has_many has_one, belongs_to should I use in each model? There should be the following methods available:

```
msg.from => author of the message
msg.to => receiver
usr.sent_messages => array of sent messages
usr.received_messages => array of received messages
```

Moreover I want the message to be destroyed when either sender or receiver is destroyed. So :dependent=>:destroy is needed somewhere

This are my attempts, which of course don't work:

User:

```
has_many :sent_messages, :source => :message, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :received_messages, :source => :message, :dependent => :destroy
```

Message:

```
has_one :from, :source=>:user
has_one :to, :source=>:user
```

Thanks in advance,

Bye

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
## User
  has_many :received_messages, :foreign_key => :to_id, :class_name => 'Message', :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :sent_messages, :foreign_key => :from_id, :class_name => 'Message', :dependent => :destroy

## Message
  belongs_to :from, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => :from_id
  belongs_to :to, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => :to_id
```

Just remember that when doing associations, when you do a **belongs_to** it means that the object that belongs is a weak entity, so it has to contain the foreign key, when you say **has_one** or **has_many**, the object that has is the **strong** entity so it does not contain the foreign key.

Think about it by the existence idea, if an object can exist without it's association, it's a **strong** entity, if it can't exist without it, it's a **weak** one.

Comment: Is every entity containing a foreign key weak entity?

Comment: It depends on if the entity can exist without the foreign key or not.